# Search class in list by name

Tags: java

I have a list of classes like this:
`[class1, class2 ... classN]`
How can I search class by name entering from scanner:

```
public static void searchClassInList() {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter value for search: ");
        String nameValue = scanner.nextLine();
        for(int i=0; i<list.size()-1; i++) {
                "How get nameField from iterated class for compare with entering value ?"
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Few problems with your code:

1. Format your code - Add spaces, new lines, make your code readable...
2. You don't have to do this `list.size - 1` just do this `list.size`.

And for your question, you can use the `getSimpleName()` method:

> https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getSimpleName--

Solution:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    
    ArrayList<Class<?>> classes = new ArrayList<>();

    System.out.println("Enter class name to search for: "); 
    String className = in.nextLine();

    in.close();
    
    for (int i = 0; i < classes.size(); i++) {
        Class<?> c = classes.get(i);
        
        if (c.getSimpleName().equals(className)) {
            System.out.println("Found!");
            return;
        }
    }
}
```